# What exactly is a view index and what happens when a viewgroup adds a view to index of -1

Tags: java, android

```
public static void addRippleToView(View v)
    {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)v.getParent();
        int index = -1;
        if(parent != null)
        {
            index = parent.indexOfChild(v);
            parent.removeView(v);
        }
        RippleViewCreator rippleViewCreator = new RippleViewCreator(v.getContext());
        rippleViewCreator.setLayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams());
        if(index == -1)
            parent.addView(rippleViewCreator, index);
        else
            parent.addView(rippleViewCreator);
        rippleViewCreator.addView(v);
    }
```

While trying to understand the code above I ran into some problems that made it difficult for me to understand.

1) I am not so sure what exactly is the index of a view which is get by calling`parent.indexOfChild(v)`?

2) Also, I have notice that the `parent.addView(rippleViewCreator,index);` What exactly happens when the index of the view is -1 and the view is added to the  parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not so sure what exactly is the index of a view which is get by
>   callingparent.indexOfChild(v)?

ViewGroup keeps its children internally a `View[]`. `indexOfChild(v)` is a linear search for v into this array. It returns the index occupied by v in it.

> What exactly happens when the index of the view is -1 and the view is
>   added to the parent?

if you don't specify an `index` or pass `-1` as index Android takes `mChildrenCount` as index, resizing the internal array in case `mChildrenCount` is equal to the array's length. The internal array is always resized by an internal factor for performance reasons

Comment: Hey Thanks for answering and the answer is very clear. However, I am sorta new to android and java so can you explains to me what is mChildrenCount?

Comment: it is just an internal member of ViewGroup which counts the real number of View in the array. The length of the array and the number of views differ

Comment: So just to verify, when I pass in -1, the viewgroup resizes its array to include the view and associates a new index to that view?

Comment: it does it if the mChildrenCount == internalArray.length

Comment: so why does mChildrenCount if equal to internalArray.length than it has to resize? I thought that the array just want to be big enough to account for all the view.

Comment: no it is not, otherwise you will have to resize if every time you add or remove a new view.

Comment: Gee Thanks I get it now

Comment: I still am a little confuse about mChildrenCount. First of all, mChildrenCount is the actual number of view in the array right? However what do you mean by "real number of View in the array"? I thought that  the array should contains all real view. Also why the array must re size when mChildrenCount == internalArray.lenght? Cause my thought process is this. If the internal array has 2 views lets say and you take out 1 then the mChildrenCount will now be one. So when you add a view, the view index which = mChildrenCount will also = 1 and therefore the size of the array is the same regardless.

Comment: The inital size of the arrey is neither 0 nor 1. Let's assume it 12. When you add the first view, mChildCount is 1 the length is 12. If you add up to 12 views, the array is resized by, again 12, and now its length is 24. Keep in mind that to resize a native array new need to instantiate a new one and copy the old content, before replacing the old reference.

Answer (score 0):

Viewgroup can contain child objects and the index says which one it is.

-1 represents non existing child because it starts from 0. If there are no child objects it gets -1 value and completes the if statement.

I don't know specificaly what rippleViewCreator is, but it should add some kind of view.